# Why would a new user role have default permissions that are greyed out and cannot be changed?

Tags: 7, users

I recently installed a new role for the LoginToBoggan module for pre-authentication, aptly named 'pre-authenticated.'

However, this user has has all the default permissions of an authenticated user, and even one that is not (Edit own comments).

If I hit 'edit permissions' to the right of the user role name on the roles page, I get the single column and can set them as desired.

However, when I look at the permissions column when all roles are listed, none of my configuration settings I had saved are honored. Also, they are greyed out and cannot be changed, giving this user permission to add and edit content. Even more of a problem, this role can indeed add and edit at will before being authenticated.

Thoughts on why this is happening and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under Drupal 7, assigning a permission to the authenticated user defaults that permission to all roles except the anonymous user. If you wish to have a lesser role (non-authenticated) you are going to have to remove the permissions from the authenticated user first. Then set up a post authentication role with the permissions you wish to add on authentication and set up a rule to assign that role when the user authenticates.

(I know! Not straight forward at all!) Remember that the permissions are additive. You do not have to repeat their assignment. Just specify the permissions that each role will add to the default. Then assign the roles to the users as required.